# Getting n number of repeated values

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, pagination

I have a table for eg.

```
        Id  FName  Lname  RowNo
       ----------------------------
        1   Aaron    K     0
        2   Aaron    L     1
        3   Arthur   M     2
        4   Arthur   G     3
        5   Arthur   D     4
        6   Ben      S     5
        7   Ben      E     6
        8   Cal      W     7
        9   Luke     A     8
        10  Mandy    N     9
```

I have implemented pagination on this table hence the row number. but my problem is instead of getting 3 rows everytime i want to get all rows with 3 repeated values. for example first i want to get all rows with the names Aaron, Arthur,Ben i.e rows 0 to 6 then the next 3 repeated values eg cal, luke and mandy and so on. Is this possible in SQL????

--edit----
 i want 3 values wich can be repeated any number of times.let me explain better. if i applied Distinct() on Name column I would get, Aaron,Arthur,Ben the first time and then cal ,luke and mandy the second time. But as the last names are different I cannot apply distinct. so insetead to getting just the distinct values I need to get the all the rows with those distinct values.i.e all rows with Aaron,Arthur and ben the first time and all rows with cal, luke and mandy the 2nd time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
declare @t table(Id int, FName varchar(10),  Lname char(1), RowNo int)
insert into  @t (Id, FName,  Lname , RowNo) values(
1,'Aaron'  ,'K', 0),
(2,'Aaron','L',1),
(3,'Arthur','M',2),
(4,'Arthur','G',3),
(5,'Arthur','D',4),
(6,'Ben', 'S',5),
(7,'Ben', 'E',6),
(8,'Cal', 'W',7),
(9,'Luke','A',8),
(10,  'Mandy','N',9)


select t.*,floor((t1.rno-1) / 3) as pge  from @t t join (select  fname,row_number() 
 over (order by fname) rno   from @t group by fname ) t1 on t.fname=t1.fname
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly, you need all rows in which FName is repeated thrice, ordered by ID.

Try this :

select FName, Lname, Id from  group by FName having count(FName) > 3 order by Id asc;

Comment: no i want 3 values wich can be repeated any number of times.let me explain better. if i applied Distinct() on Name column I would get, Aaron,Arthur,Ben the first time and then cal ,luke and mandy the second time. But as the last names are different I cannot apply distinct. so insetead to getting just the distinct values I need to get the all the rows with those distinct values.i.e all rows with Aaron,Arthur and ben the first time and all rows with cal, luke and mandy the 2nd time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  With CTE
    as
    (
    select row_number() over(partition by FName, order by Id) as rn,
    Id,FName,LName from YourTable
    )

    select * from CTE
```

this will give you the result as you needed.

you just need to append where clause with your page number. for eg, the last line of query will change to below if you want page 1.

```
select * from CTE where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution using dense_rank(). instead of row_Number(). worked perfectly.